# TCP socket not receiving in Android service after a while

Tags: android, sockets, service, tcp

My service receive phone call information from a DSL router "FRITZ!Box". When someone is calling, the router sends the phone number to my service at port 1012.
It works, but after a while my service does not receive anymore.
The service is running, that is not the reason, but it reads nothing from my router.
No exception is thrown, the service remain in while loop...

```
public class CallMonitorService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "service", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "title", "text", pendingIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground(1337, notification);

        new ListenThread().start();
    }
}

class ListenThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        Looper.prepare();

        Handler handler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                BufferedReader in = null;

                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("http://fritz.box"), 1012), 30*1000);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()), 8 * 1024);

                String line = null;

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("TAG", line);
                }


            }
        };


        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        Looper.loop();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like once your router stops sending data the loop would end and your handler exits handleMessage. At that point you would need to send another message to the handler for it to connect and start reading data again.

Also this question looks like it might be similar and deals with issues when reading data over a socket with readline. [Android TCP app hanging on inStream.readline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873366/android-tcp-app-hanging-on-instream-readline)

Hope that helps.

Comment: The printed source code is not complete, I shortened it. When the loop is exited, the handler will be called again after 30 seconds. I will try it with read() instead of readline()

Comment: It doesn't work. At the beginning, my service receive the messages, but after a while (e.g. 30 min.) the service seemed to be dead. But in Android settings - services, the service is visible and running. Could it be the "keep alive"?

Comment: Could the problem be on the other side of the connection?  Also you aren't closing this Socket after you exit the while loop and whenever handleMessage is called a new Socket is instantiated. The keep alive should preserve your TCP connection in case of network failure, you could try removing it since you are opening new connections each time handleMessage is called and see what happens.

Comment: The other side is stable sending data, because other clients (a telnet session on my PC and a telnet app on my phone) receive correctly. You are right, socket.close() is missing. But even if the loop is not ended, the problem occur. In an older version of my app, there was no keep alive, with same problem.

Comment: are you blocking on the read? I know you mentioned you changed it from readline() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359650/android-bufferedreader-readline-for-continuously-listening

Comment: Yes, read() and readline() are blocking. But that is not the reason. I tried both, with no success.